# For keyboard shortcuts "when" expression, how to check if "Fold" is enabled or "folded"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use the same key binding to fold (`editor.foldAll`) and unfold (`editor.unfoldAll`) everything in the editor. Here's my current settings:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "editor.foldAll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
    "command": "editor.unfoldAll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled"
}
```

I want to change the 'when' statement to something like this:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "editor.foldAll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled && !isFolded"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "editor.unfoldAll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled && isFolded"
}
```

But, of course, `isFolded` and anything similar don't appear to be an available 'when' clause according to the VS Code [when clause context](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts).

Is there something I'm missing or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I folded all in a file and then looked through all the context keys in the Developer Tools, and nothing looked helpful (I assume you know how to do that).

Essentially, what you want is a `toggleFoldAll` command which doesn't exist (`toggleFold` only works on the current fold, not all of them), but was requested some time ago, see [fold-all-toggle command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103644).  It didn't gain enough interest.  I think if there was a simple way to accomplish the same thing with context keys, a dev would have mentioned it.  I think you are out of luck.

You could raise an issue on gitHub asking for such a context key (although I would say that would be very hard performance-wise for the editor to keep track of whether every single possible foldable range is indeed folded or not) or ask for the `toggleFoldAll` command again.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about developer tools so thanks for the tip. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So open the Developer Tools first, clear its console, then trigger the `Developer:Inspect Context Keys` command in an editor - click anywhere.  Then back to the Developer Tools Console, open the object and Find in the Console or scan for possible keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own context variables and toggle them with the extension [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context)

You have to execute 2 commands for the key binding so you also need to use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled && !extraContext:isFolded",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "editor.foldAll",
            { "command": "extra-context.toggleVariable",
              "args": { "name": "isFolded" }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && foldingEnabled && extraContext:isFolded",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "editor.unfoldAll",
            { "command": "extra-context.toggleVariable",
              "args": { "name": "isFolded" }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```